# Using JAVA Reflection how to create custom JSON object mapping

Tags: java, reflection, objectmapper

I have a json Object in the below format, I need to assign the values from Json to java object, But the label name in JSON and class is different.

```
{
  FirstName: "Sample",
  LastName: "LName",
  Address: [
    {
      type: "Temp",
      street: "test stree",
      
    },
    {
      type: "Perm",
      street: "test stree",
      
    }
  ]
}

Class Parent{

private String Name1;
private String Nama2;
private List<Address> address;}

Class Address{

Private String type;

private String data;
}
```

I wanted to implement the custom object mapper using Java reflection. the mapping is as below, But I am not getting idea to implement this, Any valuable suggestion or usage of external api would help me to achieve the scenario.

Json Object name    Jave Class object Name
FirstName ---------- Name1
LastName  ---------- Name2
Address.type ------- Address class type
Address.street ----- Address class data

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection here? Why not either provide a custom deserializer, or add mappings to `Parent` and `Address` via Jackson's annotations or mixins?

Comment: Hi Thomas, Please let me know how can use it here with custom deserializer, i though that using reflection we need to get the fields and set the values to the class at runtime, Since we are using this kind of mapping for the first time..

Comment: Well, you could have a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization However, `@JsonProperty` annotations on the classes themselves or [mixins](https://medium.com/@shankar.ganesh.1234/jackson-mixin-a-simple-guide-to-a-powerful-feature-d984341dc9e2) for them might be the easier option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need reflexion if you receive json data with same structure with properties names changing, for example :

```
{
  FirstName1: "Sample",
  LastName1: "LName",
  Address1: [
    {
      type1: "Temp",
      street1: "test stree",
      
    },
    {
      type1: "Perm",
      street1: "test stree",
      
    }
  ]
}

{
  FirstName2: "Sample",
  LastName2: "LName",
  Address1: [
    {
      type2: "Temp",
      street2: "test stree",
      
    },
    {
      type2: "Perm",
      street2: "test stree",
      
    }
  ]
}
```

In your case, it rather look like a property name matching issue, you can annotate your java pojo like that :

```
public class Parent{

  @JsonProperty("FirstName")
  private String Name1;

  @JsonProperty("LastName")
  private String Nama2;

  private List<Address> address;
}
   
public class Address{
    
  private String type;
    
  @JsonPRoperty("street")
  private String data;
}
```

Finally you can deserialize your json object using standard Jackson library :

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Parent.class);
```